# Difference between io.sockets.sockets and io.sockets.connected

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

When running a socket.io server, each socket is collected in the io.sockets object under what appear to be identical objects: io.sockets.connected and io.sockets.sockets. As far as I can see, the data in both areas is exactly the same. Could anyone explain to be the actual difference between them?